# How do I customize the banner/header image of Hyrax/Samvera?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a web developer, trying to get my bearings with the Samvera-based application known as [Hyrax](https://github.com/samvera/hyrax). I'm using version 2.1.0.rc3. I have done some devops-type stuff with Hyrax so far, I have an app running on AWS and can deploy new code to that stack via Capistrano... but I'm tired of looking at the default header image... time to move in... however, I'm stuck. I've tried searching for terms like image-masthead in the application code, but so far, no luck. I have a suspicion this is a frequently asked question, so I'd accept as an answer just a link to a howto. But... in my searching for an answer I have not yet found such a document. So, I'm turning to Stack Overflow. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local application, search the `config/initializers/hyrax.rb` file for the string `config.banner_image` and try uncommenting it (and altering the URL to a custom image) and restart your rails server.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out the Rails asset pipeline, and I am in business, thanks!